# Why are Wilson lines the effective degrees of freedom for high energy partons?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics

I've read that Wilson lines are the effective degrees of freedom for high-energy partons, when you consider collinear gluon emission. But I'm struggling to find a readable account of this topic. Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer now. A "decoupling transformation" involving Wilson lines of soft gluons describe the effective interaction between soft gluons and collinear partons. This is described in [arxiv:hep-ph/0109045v2](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0109045).